# CouchDb 2.1.1 Admin API Compaction PUT Request

Tags: json, node.js, escaping, couchdb, config

I am working in NodeJS with CouchDB 2.1.1.

I'm using the http.request() method to set various config settings using the CouchDB API.

Here's their API reference, yes, I've read it:

[Configuration API](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/server/configuration.html#node-node-name-config)

Here's an example of a working request to set the logging level:

```
const http = require('http');

var configOptions = {
    host: 'localhost',
    path: '/_node/couchdb@localhost/_config/',
    port:5984,
    header: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};

function setLogLevel(){
    configOptions.path = configOptions.path+'log/level';
    configOptions.method = 'PUT';
    var responseString = '';
    var req = http.request(configOptions, function(res){
        res.on("data", function (data) {
            responseString += data;
        });
        res.on("end", function () {
            console.log("oldLogLevel: " + responseString);
        });
    });

    var data = '\"critical\"';

    req.write(data);
    req.end();
}

setLogLevel();
```

I had to escape all the quotes and such, which was expected.

Now I'm trying to get CouchDb to accept a setting for compaction.

The problem is that I'm attempting to replicate this same request to a different setting but that setting doesn't have a simple structure, though it appears to be "just a String" as well.

The CouchDB API is yelling at me about invalid JSON formats and I've tried a boatload of escape sequences and attempts to parse the JSON in various ways to get it to behave the way I think it should.

I can use Chrome's Advanced Rest Client to send this payload, and it is successful:

```
Request Method: PUT
Request URL: http://localhost:5984/_node/couchdb@localhost/_config/compactions/_default
Request Body:  "[{db_fragmentation, \"70%\"}, {view_fragmentation, \"60%\"}, {from, \"23:00\"}, {to, \"04:00\"}]"
```

This returns a "200 OK"

When I execute the following function in my node app, I get a response of:

```
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}

function setCompaction(){
    configOptions.path = configOptions.path+'compactions/_default';
    configOptions.method = 'PUT';
    var responseString = '';
    var req = http.request(configOptions, function(res){
        res.on("data", function (data) {
            responseString += data;
        });
        res.on("end", function () {
            console.log("oldCompaction: " + responseString); 
        });
    });

    var data = "\"[{db_fragmentation, \"70%\"}, {view_fragmentation, \"60%\"}, {from, \"23:00\"}, {to, \"04:00\"}]\"";

    req.write(data);
    req.end();
}
```

Can someone point at what I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use node's JSON module to prepare the data for transport:

```
var data = '[{db_fragmentation, "70%"}, {view_fragmentation, "60%"}, {from, "23:00"}, {to, "04:00"}]';

// Show the formatted data for the requests' payload.
JSON.stringify(data);

> '"[{db_fragmentation, \\"70%\\"}, {view_fragmentation, \\"60%\\"}, {from, \\"23:
00\\"}, {to, \\"04:00\\"}]"'

// Format data for the payload.
req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: I think I tried that but probably had some level of "escape character" hell going on at the time. Edit: This worked - thanks!

Comment: That particular CouchDB setting is deceptively easy to misinterpret - at first glance it looks like a JavaScript object, but it's really just an opaque string.